# Python deepcopy with custom __getattr__ and __setattr__

Tags: python, python-2.7, copy, getattr

I have implemented a class that can distinguish between a fixed set of instance attributes (let's call them meta-attributes) and an arbitrary set of other instance attributes.

It has custom `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, meta1, meta2, **other_attr):
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('meta1', meta1)
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('meta2', meta2)
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('params', {})

        self.params = {key: other_attr[key] for key in other_attr}


    # this is called when default lookup finds nothing
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print('__getattr__({})'.format(key))
        try:
            return self.params[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)


    # this is called always
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print('__setattr__({}, {})'.format(key, value))
        if key in self.__dict__:
            super(MyClass, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            self.params[key] = value
```

This works fine, all meta-attributes go directly into the `__dict__` of an instance, while all the other attributes go into the `params` dictionary:

```
obj1 = MyClass(meta1 = 'foo', meta2 = 'bar', x=1, y=2, z=3)
obj1.w = 4
print(obj1.__dict__)
```

*Output:*

```
__setattr__(params, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3})
__setattr__(w, 4)
{'meta1': 'foo', 'meta2': 'bar', 'params': {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3, 'w': 4}}
```

Except when I try to `deepcopy` my object, it does something strange:

```
import copy
obj1 = MyClass(meta1='foo', meta2='bar', x=1, y=2, z=3)
obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj1)
```

*Output:*

```
__setattr__(params, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3})
__getattr__(__deepcopy__)
__getattr__(__getnewargs__)
__getattr__(__getstate__)
__getattr__(__setstate__)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
__getattr__(params)
...
and then it calls __getattr__ about a hundred more times
```

In the end it *does* create a copy, but why does it make so many calls to `__getattr__`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is causing a recursive lookup (remember `obj2` is not initialised via `__init__`)

```
return self.params[key]
```

You should instead do this

```
return super().__getattribute__('params')[key]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why it does not cause an *infinite* recursion, but stops at some point?

Comment: @spiderface, I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. Perhaps you tried a version with a slightly different exception handler

Comment: That's weird. I also found out that I don't have to *return* the value from `__getattribute__`, it's sufficient to just *call* it and then return `return self.params[key]`.

Comment: to me, it was an issue when switching from python 2.7 to python3.7. __getattribute__ solved it.